# How would I get these table sections to fit the screen's width?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make these `divs` (table cells) able to fit shorter screens. For instance, the `divs` should turn into a list view on shorter screens. Instead, it clips to the end of the screen and the rest of the `divs` are inaccessible.

I have tried changing the `position` and using `table-layout` but I'm not getting any results.

```css
#container {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#section {
  color: white;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 250px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 25px;
}
#section div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="section">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div>
      This is some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
    <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    <div>
      This is some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
    <h1>Hello 3</h1>
    <div>
      This is some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
    <h1>Hello 4</h1>
    <div>
      This is some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add `margin: 25px` and `float: left` to your `#section` element. http://jsfiddle.net/9pgucybn/ (I changed the width/height to 200px but you can make it what you want)

Comment: @lurker That worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#section {
  color: white;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 250px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 25px;
}
#section div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#container {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 90px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
#section {
  color: white;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 250px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 25px;
  float: left;
}
#section div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  min-width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
}
}
```

```html
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head> 

<div id="container">
  <div id="section">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <div>
      This is some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
    <h1>Hello 2</h1>
    <div>
      This is some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
    <h1>Hello 3</h1>
    <div>
      This is some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section">
    <h1>Hello 4</h1>
    <div>
      This is some text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And as lurker said you should add some bottom or top margin

Comment: Still not working, I'm trying to have it look like a list.

Comment: well it works only with screen sizes less than 600px you said to fit smaller screens